# Erase blue border on image in HTML email

Tags: html, css, html-email

Im trying to send a HTML email and I have this piece of code:

```
<a href="#">UP &nbsp;;<img src="arrow.png" /></a></div>
```

But theres a blue border JUST around my image. How can I get rid of it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok,. guys. I was having Cache problems. It works now. I dont know which one is the right answer and I dont intent to play more with the code, but Ill give you all positive reputation. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, the best solution is to use the [deprecated](http://fantasai.tripod.com/qref/HTML4/deprecated.html) `border` attribute since not all email readers parse/apply CSS... as a separate style section, a separate sheet, or embedded in the HTML.  If you have a guaranteed audience (all using the same email viewer) then by all means use CSS if you can.

```
<a href="#">UP &nbsp;;<img src="arrow.png" border="0" /></a></div>
```

For testing here's a simple HTML document that should show all the proposed solutions:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>IMG border example</title>
    <style>.rion a img {border:0 none;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>1) Default: 
      <a href="#">UP &nbsp;;<img src="arrow.png" /></a></div>
    <div>2) Img border 1: 
      <a href="#">UP &nbsp;;<img src="arrow.png" border="1" /></a></div>
    <div>3) Img border 0: 
      <a href="#">UP &nbsp;;<img src="arrow.png" border="0" /></a></div>
    <div>4) A style border none: 
      <a href="#" style="border:none">UP &nbsp;;<img src="arrow.png" /></a></div>
    <div>5) Img style border none: 
      <a href="#" >UP &nbsp;;<img src="arrow.png" style="border:none" /></a></div>
    <div class="rion">6) Stylesheet a img style border none: 
      <a href="#" >UP &nbsp;;<img src="arrow.png" /></a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In my **browser** (Firefox) 1,2,4 show borders (default border on 1,4 is thicker), while 3,5,6 show none... however 5 & 6 rely on the email client being able to parse CSS, 6 in particular can get really dodgy with webmail clients (which mess around with style classes on base elements because they have their own CSS).

Comment: Do you have other styles in the page that might be overriding?  Does the image have an embedded border?  Is it possible the `A` element has a background colour, while the IMG has a margin so it looks like a border?

Answer (score 5):

have you tried something like this:

```
<a href="#">UP &nbsp;<img src="arrow.png" style="border:none"></a>
```

?

Answer (score 4):

Setting the `border: 0 none;` CSS property should fix that, if you wanted it to occur on all images wrapped in links, you could use it as such:

```
a img 
{
    border: 0 none;
}
```

**For use in an e-mail**, you may have to include a style block in the actual e-mail:

```
<style type='text/css'>
a img
{
    border: 0 none;
}
</style>
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sjydw/)

Comment: ! Careful, not all email readers will parse or follow CSS properties.

Comment: Did you include a style block in the e-mail? This may fix that issue.

Comment: @Dbugger how are you checking your email?

Answer (score 1):

Your image is inside a link tag (`<a>`). The blue border is caused by the default style of the link. To fix this overwrite de CSS styles of the link setting the `border` property to 0:

```
<a href="#" style="border:none">UP &nbsp;<img src="arrow.png" ></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To be on the extra safe side, specify no border in both tags.

```
<a href="#" style="border: 0;">UP &nbsp; <img src="arrow.png" style="border: 0;"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is a few months old, but I ended up here with the same question, so hopefully this may save someone the time I wasted.

The td has a background color of that neon blue, and by default has a bit of padding.

I just styled the td with...

```
style="background:none;"
```

I knew all about the border style defaults, and hadn't had the td background default in the mail clients I had previously tested, but it kept popping up in gmail.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
<a href="#">UP &nbsp;<img src="arrow.png" style="border: 0 !important;" border="0" /></a>
```

Please let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `style="background:none;"` to `td` or  adding `<style>a img {border:0 none;}</style>` has worked for me.